# How to implement a generic monte carlo algorithm for n-dimensional integration?

Tags: algorithms, integration, monte-carlo

A very visual picture for Monte Carlo integration is the approximation of $\pi$, by sampling in a square which contains a quarter of the unit circle.

We can extend this picture to 3 dimensions, by sampling a cube which contains 1/8 of a sphere.

But both cases are quite simple. I want to write a function that generalises Monte Carlo sampling for an arbitrary (yet integrable) function. Given a function $f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ how would I implement a generic algorithm? My thought process is this:

Treat $f$ as the "height" of my sampling hyperspace. If I randomly sample a point $P = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ and a random height $y$, then if $f(P) <= y$ my MC algorithm returns true, otherwise false. This picture holds in 2D and 3D dimensions, yet I'm not sure if it generalises to n-Dimensions.

Furthermore, the boundaries for a random $P$ are clearly given by the integration boundaries, which are provided. But how do I find a good boundary for $y$? I could try to find the maximum in the given interval, and then sample the hypercube.

This seems like a very visual (and thus likely ineffective) approach.

1. Is this a correct way to do it?
2. Is there a better way?

Comment: This is well described on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration